# AWS ATHENA: user-defined variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, variables, session-variables, amazon-athena

I need to create a row number by group. In mysql I use "user-defined variables" for that.
But in Athena is gives me an error: no viable alternative at input '@'

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  @row_num := IF(@prev_value=concat_ws('',t.user_id,t.campaign_id,t.placement_id, t.creative_id),@row_num+1,1) AS RowNumber
     ,t.user_id 
     ,t.campaign_id
     ,t.placement_id
     ,t.creative_id
     , t.imp_clk_event_dt
     ,@prev_value := concat_ws('',t.user_id,t.campaign_id,t.placement_id, t.creative_id)
FROM e2c_conv t,
     (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
     (SELECT @prev_value := '') y ORDER BY t.user_id,t.campaign_id,t.placement_id, t.creative_id, t.imp_clk_event_dt
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: athena doesn't support `concat_ws` like HIVE does

Comment: Presto is now called Trino

Answer (score 10):

**TLDR:** AWS Athena does not support variables.

As per their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/athena/latest/ug/functions-operators-reference-section.html), AWS Athena is based on [Presto 0.172](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/index.html) with some [limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/athena/latest/ug/other-notable-limitations). Presto currently has an open issue where the addition of variables is being discussed. [PR-5918](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/5918)

Comment: Is this still true (posting comment on 04/28/2021)?

Comment: Update, as of today, Athena still does not support user_defined variables. I love it when developers create their own duplicative languages just so they can have their own syntax and desired commands. :\

Answer (score 8):

```
with Mandeep as 
              ( 
               select 123 as m_1
                    , 234 as m_2
                ) -- Variable_table (Define Variables here)
select * 
from (
select 123 as a
      , 'abc' as v) as b 
left join Mandeep as m on 1 = 1 - mapping with rows
where a = m.m_1 -- using variables
```

Answer (score 4):

Athena now supports [Prepared Statements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-with-prepared-statements.html) for parameterized queries:

> You can use the Athena parameterized query feature to prepare statements for repeated execution of the same query with different query parameters. A prepared statement contains parameter placeholders whose values are supplied at execution time. Prepared statements enable Athena queries to take parameters directly and help to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Query :

```sql
with man as ( select ('123') as m_number  
         ) 
select *
from table_name as t 
left join man as m on 1=1
where t.number = man.m_number
```

Comment: Presto is now called Trino

Comment: @JosephDoggie Presto is not called Trino. PrestoSQL is. Ref: https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html